# Drag and drop from file explorer to div not working on chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to drag and drop files from the Windows File Explorer to a div. I have some code that i've written with help from research (mostly on stackoverflow), and i've tested in IE, FireFox and Chrome. The code works for IE and FireFox but not Chrome... am i doing something wrong? Here's my javascript:

```
var _enableDragAndDrop = function () {

        if (_isAdvancedUpload.call(this)) {
            $(".excelDragAndDropContainer")
                .on("dragover", _preventDefault.bind(this))
                .on("dragenter", _preventDefault.bind(this))
                .on("drop", function () {
                    var test = 0;
                });
        }
        else {
            $(".dragHere").addClass("hidden");
        }
    };

var _isAdvancedUpload = function () {
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        return (('draggable' in div) || ('ondragstart' in div && 'ondrop' in div)) && 'FormData' in window && 'FileReader' in window;
    };

var _preventDefault = function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    };
```

CLARIFICATION: By "not working" i mean that in chrome i get a "ban circle" symbol when i drag the file on the screen, and it doesn't even reach the `_preventDefault` function, whereas in IE/FireFox once i drag into the div it triggers the `_preventDefault` function